# Is there anything like biblist for use with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

Is anyone aware of a modern tool that can be used with `biblatex`to produce a structured list of an entire BibTeX database, like to old \biblist\ under LaTeX 2.09?

Comment: There are three styles that should get you started at least.  See the example docs: `02-annotations.pdf`, `80-style-reading.pdf`, and `82-style-debug.pdf`.  If you have TeX Live: use `texdoc 02-annotations` (etc.).

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a comment, there are several options here. Probably the best is the `reading` style, which can be used for example with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=reading,abstract=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{<database>.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

One might use the `deubg` style but this is probably too low-level for the task at hand (it really is a data-dump). The exact appearance of the `reading` style is not the same as `biblist` but one could adjust this relatively easily: the entire point of `biblatex` is that styling can be undertaken in the LaTeX document.